# Apple Watch's known WiFi network?

Tags: ios, wifi, keychain, apple-watch

I'm unsure about the definition of 'known Wifi network' for Apple Watch. Does the Watch has to be connected to it through once before, or just any Wifi that the iPhone has login credentials?

To be more clear:

When the Watch-iPhone are connected, are all WIFI logins automatically synced from iPhone to the Watch?

Or only the currently-connected-WIFI-login will be automatically synced to the Watch?

Thanks very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple generally syncs such credentials to your devices through iCloud. But in order to sync, your device needs to be on a network.

So, if your iPhone is on a new Wifi, iCloud will get the credentials and all your devices will get them whenever they have Internet access.
It should also sync if your iPhone is connected with Bluetooth to your Watch, and at **the same time** connected to the network, according to this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204562

Have you tried connecting your Apple Watch on a different network to see if it gets the new Wifi credentials of the iPhone?

The Watch cannot connect to private networks without the use of your iPhone *(or iCloud in general)*.